# SQL Injection attack asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I made aN SQl injection into my database as a test to my Login page. User has a number of attempts to insert correct username and password correctly. However, when user fails to enter correct data, then would be directed into another web form for password recovery. In the password recovery form, user will get the user name shown (if existed on the data base) and few character of email address as a reminder! Then user can confirm the full email address into a text box to send personal details into that email.
I tried to inject my sql using this test:

```
        ' or'a'='a
```

This code was entered into the username field and password and after certain attempts I was directed into the password recovery page and I have the first email into my database shown to me as a member!! It means this code enabled me to access the first row into my database. Is there any way I can prevent these kind of attack on my code, i.e encrypting my SQl statement !

Comment: Check out about [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: how about removing the inline dynamic sqls and use stored procs to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

Use stored procedures or at least parameterized queries, don't use string concatenation.

Comment: How to do this in my select statement I've never used Parameterized queries before ?

Comment: Use the SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue method, it's documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I just want to alter the last select statement in the MailCheck method, but still find it a bit confusing to do that as Paramaterized query